# NX for Angular preventing certain operations from running?

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, powershell, node-modules

With NX 14.8.1 for Angular 14.2.4, the file 'node_modules/.cache/nx/d/daemon.log' is preventing operations such as yarn install from running properly. When running yarn install, the following error is displayed in the console.

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\*user*\Programming\*project*\*project2*\ClientApp\node_modules.cache\nx\d\daemon.log'

Note: user, project, and project 2 are replacements for the real directories. user has a space in it, which has caused problems for nx before.

The file daemon.log does not allow me to delete it via File Explorer or PowerShell rm. File Explorer prompts for Admin but says that access is denied when I do, and PowerShell fails to run with an access is denied error. I am also unable to delete it via rm in Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu, with a similar error to PowerShell rm. In File Explorer, I am unable to edit the permissions of the file to allow it to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems funny but using any file unlocker would help.
I just use IOrbit unlocker to unlock and delete the deamon.log and nx build just started working.